# How NOHZ=ON affects do_timer() in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, time, timer, linux-kernel

In a simple experiment I set `NOHZ=OFF` and used `printk()` to print how often the `do_timer()` function gets called. It gets called every 10 ms on my machine.

However if `NOHZ=ON` then there is a lot of jitter in the way `do_timer()` gets called. Most of the times it does get called every 10 ms but there are times when it completely misses the deadlines.

I have researched about both `do_timer()` and NOHZ. `do_timer()` is the function responsible for updating `jiffies` value and is also responsible for the round robin scheduling of the processes.

NOHZ feature switches off the hi-res timers on the system.

What I am unable to understand is how can hi-res timers affect the `do_timer()`? Even if hi-res hardware is in sleep state the persistent clock is more than capable to execute `do_timer()` every 10 ms. Secondly if `do_timer()` is not executing when it should, that means some processes are not getting their timeshare when they should ideally be getting it. A lot of googling does show that for many people many applications start working much better when `NOHZ=OFF`.

To make long story short, how does `NOHZ=ON` affect `do_timer()`?
Why does `do_timer()` miss its deadlines?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First lets understand what is a `tickless kernel` ( `NOHZ=On` or `CONFIG_NO_HZ` set ) and what was the motivation of introducing it into the Linux Kernel from `2.6.17`

From http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/tickless/index.php,

> Traditionally, the Linux kernel used a periodic timer for each CPU.
>   This timer did a variety of things, such as process accounting,
>   scheduler load balancing, and maintaining per-CPU timer events. Older
>   Linux kernels used a timer with a frequency of 100Hz (100 timer events
>   per second or one event every 10ms), while newer kernels use 250Hz
>   (250 events per second or one event every 4ms) or 1000Hz (1000 events
>   per second or one event every 1ms).
>
> This periodic timer event is often called "the timer tick". The timer
>   tick is simple in its design, but has a significant drawback: the
>   timer tick happens periodically, irrespective of the processor state,
>   whether it's idle or busy. If the processor is idle, it has to wake up
>   from its power saving sleep state every 1, 4, or 10 milliseconds. This
>   costs quite a bit of energy, consuming battery life in laptops and
>   causing unnecessary power consumption in servers.
>
> With "tickless idle", the Linux kernel has eliminated this periodic
>   timer tick when the CPU is idle. This allows the CPU to remain in
>   power saving states for a longer period of time, reducing the overall
>   system power consumption.

So reducing power consumption was one of the main motivations of the tickless kernel. But as it goes, most of the times, Performance takes a hit with decreased power consumption. For desktop computers, performance is of utmost concern and hence you see that for most of them `NOHZ=OFF` works pretty well.

In Ingo Molnar's own words

> The tickless kernel feature (CONFIG_NO_HZ) enables 'on-demand' timer
>   interrupts: if there is no timer to be expired for say 1.5 seconds
>   when the system goes idle, then the system will stay totally idle for
>   1.5 seconds. This should bring cooler CPUs and power savings: on our (x86) testboxes we have measured the effective IRQ rate to go from HZ
>   to 1-2 timer interrupts per second.

Now, lets try to answer your queries-

> What I am unable to understand is how can hi-res timers affect the
>   do_timer ?

If a system supports high-res timers, timer interrupts can occur more frequently than the usual `10ms` on most systems. i.e these timers try to make the system more responsive by leveraging the system capabilities and by firing timer interrupts even faster, say every `100us`. So with `NOHZ` option, these timers are cooled down and hence the lower execution of `do_timer`

> Even if hi-res hardware is in sleep state the persistent clock is more
>   than capable to execute do_timer every 10ms

Yes it is capable. But the intention of `NOHZ` is exactly the opposite. To prevent frequent timer interrupts!

> Secondly if do_timer is not executing when it should that means some
>   processes are not getting their timeshare when they should ideally be
>   getting it

As [caf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134633/caf) noted in the comments, `NOHZ` does not cause processes to get scheduled less often, because it only kicks in when the CPU is idle - in other words, when no processes are schedulable. Only the process accounting stuff will be done at a delayed time.

> Why does do_timer miss it's deadlines ?

As elaborated, it is the intended design of `NOHZ`

I suggest you go through the [tick-sched.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/tick-sched.c) kernel sources as a starting point. Search for `CONFIG_NO_HZ` and try understanding the new functionality added for the `NOHZ` feature

Here is one test performed to measure the [Impact of a Tickless Kernel](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=651&num=1)

Comment: I am more than thankful for this answer. I was under impression that NOHZ affects only hires timers and hence do_timer is not affected in any ways (I thought do_timer was fired by persistent clock only which is not affected by NOHZ switch).

Comment: `NOHZ` does *not* cause processes to get scheduled less often, because it only kicks in when the CPU is idle - in other words, when *no processes are schedulable*.

Comment: @caf Thanks a lot for the pointer caf. Updated my answer with your comments :)
So, if `NOHZ` doesn't affect process scheduling, then why does the performance ( like system freezes ) improve when `NOHZ=OFF`? I've seen many people complaining about this is forums.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: It's possible that some badly written userspace applications or input drivers interact badly with `NOHZ`, but in most cases I suspect that those people are simply mistaken.