# How are jiffies incremented in a tickless kernel?

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Kernel maintains a global variable called `jiffies` which holds the number of ticks/timer interrupts from system boot.

Every time a timer interrupt occurs, the value of an internal kernel counter is incremented.

In tickless kernel/dynamic ticks, where the interrupts does not happen periodically, how is the value of `jiffies` incremented?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775042/how-nohz-on-affects-do-timer-in-linux-kernel

Comment: This question [How SMP scheduling works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182160/how-smp-schedule-work-in-linux-kernel-arm-architecture) may also be of interest.  'Tickless' is not without interrupts.  'Tickless' will not wake if there is no work to do.  When there is work to do, instead of adding '1' tick to jiffies, the timer interrupt will add ticks since last interrupt.  Since there is no work, there is no one to look at jiffies.  For other interrupt sources, the timer chip hardware can read 'jiffies' before executing that code to correct the value.

Answer (score 8):

The value of `jiffies` is always updated calling the [`do_timer()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L2194) function from the timer interrupt handler, no matter the configuration. What really changes between a "normal" and a "tickless" kernel is only *when* such interrupts can happen.

First, let me clarify that there is no such thing as a real "tickless" kernel. The kernel will always need ticks to happen on at least one CPU. Unless all CPUs are idle, at least one CPU must keep the scheduling-clock interrupt going in order to support accurate timekeeping. I highly recommend reading [`Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt) for more very useful and insightful information on the topic.

In particular, the `jiffies` value is only updated by the same CPU (i.e. the global variable [`tick_do_timer_cpu`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/time/tick-common.c#L35)). The two following scenarios are possible:

- In case of periodic ticks, the [`tick_handle_periodic()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/time/tick-common.c#L103) handler is used. This handler simply calls [`tick_periodic()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/time/tick-common.c#L83), which then calls `do_timer(1)` incrementing `jiffies` by `1` tick.
- In case of non-periodic ticks, the [`tick_nohz_handler()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/time/tick-sched.c#L1204) is used. This handler calls [`tick_sched_do_timer()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/time/tick-sched.c#L117), which calls [`tick_do_update_jiffies64()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/time/tick-sched.c#L54), which updates `jiffies` dynamically calculating the number of ticks that happened since the last update (which can be more than `1`), with the help of the `ktime_t` passed by `tick_nohz_handler()` and obtained through `ktime_get()`.

Comment: How often does tick happen in "tickless" kernel on that "timekeeping CPU(s)"? If we have 100Hz, does the frequency on tickless and non-tickless kernels the same?

Comment: *"the jiffies value is only updated by the same CPU"* - just on "tickless" kernel or anyway?

Comment: @narotello the frequency is the same, the only difference is that "tickless" kernels are able to "pause" the ticking when the cpu does not need it (e.g. idle). `jiffies` is always updated by the same CPU, if you check the code you'll see that there's always a check of the kind `if (cpu == tick_do_timer_cpu)` before calling `do_timer()`.

Comment: *""pause" the ticking when the cpu does not need it (e.g. idle)"* - so at least one CPU can never be idle (ever needs ticking)? In other words "timekeeping CPU" is always ticking? Is that CPU statically defined at boot load or is the particular CPU unknown for each subsequent tick?

Comment: @narotello if you read the kernel documentation page that I linked you'll understand this a lot better. There are three modes available: `CONFIG_HZ_PERIODIC`, `CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE` and `CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL`. The default on modern kernels is `CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE`. There always needs to be *at least 1* CPU that is *not* in `NO_HZ_FULL`. This does not exclude the possibility that all CPUs are idle at the same time, that can still happen, and in that case there actually is no need to have ticks and maintain updated timers, that's only needed if at least one task is running (on any CPU).

Comment: @narotello if there's only one task and it's running on the main CPU, then the main CPU needs to keep ticking. If the task is running on *another CPU*, then the main CPU *still needs* to keep ticking, while the one that is running the task does not necessarily need to (since there's only one task) and can run "tickless".

Comment: I read but don't quite understand :( Thank you a lot for clarification. But what do you mean by *main CPU*? Are CPUs not equivalent to each other? And I still don't understand, is that (e.g. one) CPU (that is not in `NO_HZ_FULL`) defined at boot-time or it is dynamically distributed role? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @narotello it's all very clearly explained in the document I linked. If you have doubts or questions about the topic you should [ask an actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), rather than post comments under an existing answer that is only *related* to your questions.