# Understanding the `scheduler_tick()` function of Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, scheduler

To my knowledge, I understood that the `scheduler_tick()` function periodically gets called by the timer interrupt with the frequency of HZ.

I'm new to kernel development, so these might be naive questions but I'm trying to understand the execution of the `scheduler_tick()` function. I'd appreciate your help on these questions:

1. It is possible for the timer to invoke this function again before the previous call returns?
2. Is it called per-core? (with per-core timer interrupt)
3. If the HZ frequency is high, the scheduler executes a process for longer than its timeslice. If the HZ is low, I presume a significant overhead due to frequent interruptions and invocation of this function. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: 1. No, interrupts are disabled. 2. Yes, first instruction reads CPU id. 3. Pretty much.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Regarding the second question, does it mean that all the cores execute it when their timer interrupt triggers? If so, does it mean that all cores trigger the periodic load balancer almost at the same time?! @stark

Comment: Each core schedules tasks for itself.

Comment: As per point 3 it's the opposite actually: if HZ is low, there will be *less* invocations of the scheduler. HZ is the amount of times the interrupt happens per second. Other than that, your understanding is correct. Scheduling on every single core simultaneously is not needed, and I don't think it happens, each CPU has its own timer and does its own timer interrupts regardless of sync with other CPUs.

Comment: `trigger_load_balance` is called at the end of `scheduler_tick` which I assume performs the periodic load balancing on all cores. Is it called on each core timer interrupt? @stark

Comment: See also [Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt) and [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174030/3889449).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks for the clarification. I assume `trigger_load_balance` should be called once per all cores in a given interval. How does it happen? I see no locking in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your main questions and comments at the same time:

1. It's not possible for scheduler code to be called *while already scheduling*, as it runs with interrupts disabled.
2. Yes, each core has its own runqueue and does its own scheduling.
3. It's the opposite: high HZ -> scheduler will run more frequently (since HZ represents the number of scheduling ticks per second); low HZ -> scheduler will run less frequently.

Scheduling on every single core simultaneously is not needed, each CPU has its own timer and does its own timer interrupts regardless of sync with other CPUs. Scheduler ticks don't happen at the same time on all CPUs (furthermore CPUs could be idle and not ticking at all in a "tickless" kernel, configured with `CONFIG_NOHZ`). Tickless kernels make things a bit tricker, for more info check out [Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt) and [*"How are jiffies incremented in a tickless kernel?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174030/3889449).

As per what `trigger_load_balance()` does and how, see [Documentation/scheduler/sched-domains.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-domains.txt), which explains it more or less in detail. In particular, `trigger_load_balance()` doesn't do the actual load balancing, it just checks if it's needed and if so raises a soft IRQ (`SCHED_SOFTIRQ`), which is then handled by [`run_rebalance_domains()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.7/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L10975), which calls [`rebalance_domains()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.7/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L10263), which does the actual work. The latter function indeed uses RCU/locking, as you can see by the calls to functions such as `spin_trylock()` and `rcu_read_lock()`.