# What causes apic_timer_interrupt()?

Tags: linux-kernel, centos7, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I am on CentOS 7 (kernel 3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64).

For some reasons, my application with tight loop (on an isolated core, which is on `nohz_full` list) has `apic_timer_interrupt` about once every 1 sec.  This isn't the local timer interrupt.

My dummy application:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        srand(time(nullptr));
        int32_t i = 0;
        while (i != rand()) i = rand() * -1;
        printf("%d", i);
}
```

`/proc/sched_debug` showed that the core only had one task:

```
cpu#5, 2900.000 MHz
  .nr_running                    : 1
```

`dmesg` showed that the core is using dynamic tick:

```
[Sun Mar 15 23:11:30 2020] NO_HZ: Full dynticks CPUs: 2-11.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Yes, it's a synchronization tick of the scheduler IIUC. I will find later the QA link which discuss this.

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775042/how-nohz-on-affects-do-timer-in-linux-kernel

Comment: @0andriy thanks for sharing the link.  I actually have the core (the application bound to) on `nohz_full` and I have confirmed with `dmesg` that the core is indeed with dynamic tick and I also have confirmed that there is only 1 runnable task in `/proc/sched_debug` on that core.  Hence, in my case, it is not related the interrupt generated by the tick.